# Decoding JSON-like object using the json module

Tags: python, json

I want to be able to decode a format that looks like JSON, but can handle hexadecimal content. Let's call it JSHON. Example content:

```
{
    "nine": 9,
    "ten":  0xA,
    "eleven": 11
}
```

Is it easy to coax [the stdlib json module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to provide such an ability, or should I use something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix would be to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval),

```
>>> data = '''
... {
...     "nine": 9,
...     "ten":  0xA,
...     "eleven": 11
... }
... '''
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(data)
{'eleven': 11, 'nine': 9, 'ten': 10}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot easier than I hoped :)

Comment: Be careful though, as values like `null` (which the JSON decoder would interpret as `None`) will cause it to fail...

Answer (score 0):

According to its documentation, [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson) supports this (in its non-strict mode). It has no support for Python 3 yet, but it will do for now.

Comment: Thanks to Jon Clements for pointing this to me: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=11075790#11075790.